# Correlating multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I was trying to  extend the above link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalkcpr/archive/2009/10/05/inserting-parent-child-records-with-identity-column-using-wcf-sql-adapter-in-one-transaction.aspx#comments

My problem is :

I have three table....the first two tables have `id` as `IDENTITY`... I need to get the `id` of first table in 2nd table

Then I need to get `id` of 1st and 2nd table in 3rd table ..... I was able to get `id` of first table into 2nd table

But I'm not able to get `id` of 2nd table into 3rd table...........I am using WCF SQL  adapter to consume the stored procedure and my stored procedure looks like this

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[InsertHeader]
(
   @parHeader As Header READONLY,
   @parHeader_Details As HeaderDetails READONLY,
   @parHeader_Details1 As HeaderDetails1 READONLY
)
AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON

 BEGIN

 DECLARE @id int, @id1 int

 INSERT INTO EDI834_5010_Header([File_Name_EDI834], [ST01], [ST02], [ST03], 
                                [BGN01__TransactionSetPurposeCode],
                                [BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode],
                                [BGN03__TransactionSetCreationDate],
                                [BGN04__TransactionSetCreationTime],
                                [BGN08__ActionCode], [SE01], [SE02])
    SELECT  
       [File_Name_EDI834], [ST01], [ST02], [ST03],
       [BGN01__TransactionSetPurposeCode], [BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode],
       [BGN03__TransactionSetCreationDate], [BGN04__TransactionSetCreationTime],  
       [BGN08__ActionCode], [SE01], [SE02] 
    FROM @parHeader;

 SET @id = @@IDENTITY;

 INSERT INTO EDI834_5010_2000([Header_Id], [INS01__InsuredIndicator],
                              [INS02__IndividualRelationshipCode],
                              [INS03__MaintenanceTypeCode],
                              [INS04__MaintenanceReasonCode],
                              [INS05__BenefitStatusCode])
    SELECT @id, [INS01__InsuredIndicator], [INS02__IndividualRelationshipCode],
           [INS03__MaintenanceTypeCode], [INS04__MaintenanceReasonCode],
           [INS05__BenefitStatusCode] 
    FROM @parHeader_Details;

 SET @id1 = @@IDENTITY;

 INSERT INTO EDI834_5010_2300Loop([Id_Header_Id], [Id_Loop2000],
                                  [HD01_MaintenanceTypeCode], [HD03_InsuranceLineCode],
                                  [HD04_PlanCoverageDescription])
    SELECT @id, @id1,
           HD01_MaintenanceTypeCode, HD03_InsuranceLineCode,
           HD04_PlanCoverageDescription 
    FROM @parHeader_Details1;

  RETURN @id1;
 END
```

What do I need to change in my stored procedure to get the `id` of 2nd table into 3rd....... there are so many looping in xml so I need to get the appropriate ids in 3rd table

And my data looks like this

```
 <Header details>

         <Header_Details1>  data   </Header_Details>

          <Header_Details1>  data   </Header_Details>

           <Header_Details1>  data   </Header_Details>

  <Header_details>

  <Header details>

         <Header_Details1>  data   </Header_Details>

          <Header_Details1>  data   </Header_Details>

           <Header_Details1>  data   </Header_Details>

  <Header_details>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: ...and breaking long lines into shorter ones would also help. A lot.

Comment: Who on earth comes up with these **table and column names** ?!?!??!?!?

Comment: Hey mark_S :) about column names and table names these are 837 X12files.....there column is like this only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your main problem is: you're not just inserting a single row - but a whole bunch of rows!

So while you can use `@@IDENTITY` to get the last inserted identity value (btw: I would recommend using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead - [see here as for why](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)) - this will **only** work for a single row!

What you need is a mechanism to output multiple inserted identities - [use the OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

```
DECLARE @InsertedIDs TABLE (ID1 INT, ID2 INT)

INSERT INTO EDI834_5010_Header(......)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID INTO @InsertedIDs(ID1) 
SELECT  
   ....... 
FROM @parHeader;
```

For the first statement, this will output all inserted identity values into the table variable `@InsertedIDs`.

Now for your second table - is there any column that you can relate the first and second inserted ID's by?? You would need to capture the inserted identity values from the second `INSERT` into the same table variable, but you need to somehow know which `ID1` to associate with with `ID2` - and I quite frankly don't see how that would be done in your statements.....

But in the end, you would have a table variable with n rows of `(ID1, ID2)` which you can then use to insert into your third table.

Comment: my data look like this                                                    <Header>

     <Header details>

             <Header_Details1>  data   </Header_Details>

              <Header_Details1>  data   </Header_Details>

               <Header_Details1>  data   </Header_Details>

      <Header_details>

      <Header details>

             <Header_Details1>  data   </Header_Details>

              <Header_Details1>  data   </Header_Details>

               <Header_Details1>  data   </Header_Details>

      <Header_details>

 </Header>

Comment: @user1104946: please **do not** post large text or XML snippets into comments - next to impossible to read! Please instead: **update** your original question by **editing it** and provide that information there - thank you!